# tcpdump capture limit size with latest capture

Tags: linux, tcpdump

tcpdump -W 5 -C 10 -w capfile
I know what this command does, which is rotating buffer of 5 files (-W 5) and tcpdump switches to another file once the current file reaches 10,000,000 bytes, about 10MB (-C works in units of 1,000,000 bytes, so -C 10 = 10,000,000 bytes). The prefix of the files will be capfile (-w capfile), and a one-digit integer will be appended to each: [how to save a new file when tcpdum file size reaches 10Mb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567963/how-to-save-a-new-file-when-tcpdum-file-size-reaches-10mb/49436777#49436777)

My question is what happens if I set -W to 1:
tcpdump -W 1 -C 10 -w capfile

Is this gonna only have 1 file with max size 10 MB contains the latest capture?

Comment: for tcpdump -W 5 -C 10 -w capfile, it will have capfie0 to capfile4 each has max size of 10 MB. if I set -W to 1, is it gonna create a file has the latest 10MB capture which is same as capfile4?

Comment: I have to say that this question is so trivial that you can answer it yourself in about 5 minutes.  Have you actually tried what you are proposing to see how the tool behaves?